# How to generate a feasible point for a program with both equality and inequality contraints?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, constraints

I am using an optimization method that requires a starting point within the feasible domain:

$$\min f(x)$$

$$Ax=b$$

$$Cx>r$$

where

$$x \in R^l$$

$$b \in R^n$$

$$r \in R^m$$

and

$$ (m+n) > l $$

In other words, the amount of equality/inequality constraint equations is greater that the amount of unknowns.  Also, note that $l>n$  so in general there should be a feasible solution in existence.

What is the best approach to generate any feasible point to start the program?  Thanks.

Comment: $>$ is a difficult concept in optimization. $\ge$ is more appropriate. To get a feasible solution, you could throw this at any LP solver (with an all zero objective).

Comment: If you use an interior point method as LP solver, there is better chance to fulfill the strict inequality. With a simplex method you need to add some perturbation to $r$.

Comment: @user251257, Erwin, Guy. Thank you for the interesting problem and discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing nothing about $A, C, b, y$ except dimensions a bit, this is a pretty hopeless task.

We can write
$$
C x > r \quad (*)
$$
as
$$
C x \ge r + \epsilon \quad (**) \\
\epsilon > 0
$$
where $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}^m$ is some vector with positive components.
I have no idea how to pick this in a smart way. This way one can model it as LP problem. A solution $x$ fulfilling $(**)$ should fulfill $(*)$:

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to understand your old suggestion. I think your new method (least squares) does not obey $Ax=b$ in general.

Answer (score 0):

Most LP solvers have pretty clever ways to generate the initial iterate. If you want to do it yourself, consider following auxiliary  LP:
$ \max y $
for $Ax=b$, $Cx - ye \ge r$, $y\le 1$, where $e$ is the vector with ones.

Solve that auxiliary LP with what method you like, if the optimal $y^*$ is positive, you obtain your feasible $x$. If $y^* \le 0$, there is no feasible point. However due to rounding error, you need to check this with some tolerance.

To obtain a  feasible point for the auxiliary LP: Compute a solution of $Ax=b$ (for example by factorization). Then set $y$ to some value less than (or equal) the least component of $Cx - r$. If $y>0$ you are done, otherwise solve the auxiliary LP. You could stop, if you reach some iterate with $y>0$.